# C dynamic memory allocation. Issue with allocating an array of arrays dynamically

Tags: c, memory, dynamic

I created a struct, called ArrayCount, that contains a double array and an integer that should count how often an array occurs.

If the size of the double-array is n, the idea is, to create an array of the struct ArrayCount of the size n! (n! is called m in my code).

The idea is to safe each permutation in the ArrayCount-array, counting the occurrences of each permutation, for a given algorithm. 
But that's just the background information and not part of the problem.

I am having issues allocating the memory. The allocation for the Array-Count array works fine, but I can't allocate the memory for the double-arrays that are included.

The error message is:

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
```

And the error is occurring during the initiate_array_counts function, when I try to allocate the memory with "double* `array_counts[i].array = calloc(n, 8);`.

Thanks in advance,
Timo

```
typedef struct {
double* array;
int counter;
} ArrayCount;

void initiate_array_counts(/*INOUT*/ArrayCount* array_counts, 
/*IN*/int n){
    int m = factorial(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        double* array_counts[i].array = calloc(n, 8);
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            array_counts[i].array[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void shuffle_frequency(int n) {
    double a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = i; // 0, 1, 2, ..., n - 1
    }
    int m = factorial(n);
    ArrayCount* array_counts = calloc(m, sizeof(ArrayCount));
    initiate_array_counts(array_counts, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000 * m; i++) {
        shuffle(a, n);
        update_array_counts(array_counts, m, a, n);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                printf("%4d%8d    ", i, array_counts[i].counter);
        printdaln(array_counts[i].array, n);
    }
    free(array_counts);
}
```

(I included only the necessary code)

Comment: remove `double*`. You are not defining anything here.

Comment: you wanted `array_counts[i].array = (double *)calloc(n, 8);` instead

Comment: Aside: rather than `calloc(n, 8)`, avoid magic numbers.  Suggest `calloc(n, sizeof array_counts[i].array[0]);`

Comment: Note that 32-bit integers can only store up to factorial 12.

Comment: See also Timo's [more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53862059/different-error-messages-while-freeing-allocated-memory).  It doesn't seem to have been said here, but it helps enormously if you provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've not done that, so we can only wave hands around and guess.  You don't show the `shuffle()` code; you don't show the `update_array_counts()` code; those are candidates for causing trouble.  The printing function is less likely to cause trouble, but it could.  And there's no `main()` function, so we don't know what parameters you're using.

Comment: (The more recent question has been deleted, so it is only visible to those with 10K rep.)